# multiple ng-grids on one page performance issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I want to use multiple ng-grids on single page I am successful in implementing them but the real problem arises here:

I want to have like more than 30 grids on single page.
Here is how am I rendering them:

```
<div ng-repeat="dataGrid in dataGrids">
    <div ng-grid="dataGrid.grid"></div>  
</div>
```

now when there are 5-6 girds then everything works fine but when number of grids exceeds 10 the page starts to hang up it become unresponsive for minutes.
Is there any solution to this?

like:
**how can I manage this by putting 30 grids on a page?**

Comment: why do you need 30 grids. Do you have 30 dynamically updating sets of data , you can change to a static table for non-updating parts.  Also, try the newer [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) , its supposed to be much faster

Comment: hi @arkoak thanks for replying
i just need to show information and have grids with pagination feature there is no updation in  data is fetching from beck-end and just needed to render at front end with pagination,is there any other solution you can provide i would really appreciate that thanks allot